# An algorithm for generating sequences based on limited information

Tags: algorithm, graph, sequence

Let's say we have a set of letters, e.g. {A,B,C,D,E,F} that we want to arrange in sequence, constrained by a set of rules.

We do not know what the sequence looks like, but we do know what letters are in the sequence. And we have information on ordering of pairs of letters. Are there any well-known algorithms or methods that will find the possible sequences which satisfy the given information?

For example, let's say we have the following information:

- There are 6 letters {A,B,C,D,E,F} in the sequence
- E comes after B
- C comes after E
- A comes after D
- F comes after B
- D comes after E

What are the possible sequences that satisfy these criteria?

Answer (score 2):

build a Directed Graph G(V,E)
`V = {a,b,c,d,e}` your letters
`E = (x,y) for any pair where x comes before y.`

then use Topological Sort ([read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)) ([visualization here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/TopoSortDFS.html))

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS).

In your example, the initial state of the problem is

```
------ abcdef
BE
EC
DA
BF
ED
```

which is to say that no letters have been added to the sequence, the remaining available letters are `abcdef` and the remaining rules are *"`B` must come before `E`"*, etc.

None of the letters on the right side of a rule can be chosen as the next letter. Therefore `B` is the only choice for the first letter. The new problem state is

```
B----- acdef
EC
DA
ED
```

The rules pertaining to `B` have been satisfied and serve no further purpose. The second letter must be `E` or `F`, since `ACD` appear on the right-hand side of a rule. Assuming that the DFS explores `E` first, the new state is

```
BE---- acdf
DA
```

Allowed choices are `CDF` since `A` is still on the right-hand side of a rule. Choose `C`

```
BEC--- adf
DA
```

Allowed choices are `DF`. Choose `D`

```
BECD-- af
```

Choose `A`, then `F`, and the sequence is complete

```
BECDAF
```

After reaching a solution, the DFS must go back and explore the other options. For example, choosing `F` instead of `E` as the second letter.